# Nginx+Tomcat+Docker compose SSL

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, tomcat, docker-compose

I have angular client application running on Nginx and Spring boot application as rest service for the angular client running on tomcat.

I am running the both applications through docker compose.

I have a single DNS portal.example.com.

How to apply SSL for the client(running on Nginx) and service(running on Tomcat) applications with single(same) DNS?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Nginx as a reverse proxy for the Spring boot application (in fact, I realized some similar architectures myself).

Nginx would then serve the application if requested for `/` (say) and act as a reverse proxy for the Spring boot application when requested for `/api` (say).

In this case, you simply configure SSL in the Nginx proxy following [the documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html).

Ask freely if you need more details about my suggested solution.

The architecture can be represented graphically as:

```
          ( request to / ) -------> Angular 
Nginx ---<
          ( request to /api ) ----> Spring Boot
```

Comment: I'm glad of that, if it is as you say, please accept it as the answer of your question!
I want to point out another interesting answer to a related question: view it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45296590/aws-ecs-production-docker-deployment/45301117#45301117). Hope you find it profitable. The argument there is different, but still it points out some interesting advantages of putting a reverse proxy in front of your applications.